# How to convert DataFrame columns from string to float/double in PySpark 1.6?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, type-conversion

In PySpark 1.6 DataFrame currently there is no Spark builtin function to convert from string to float/double.

Assume, we have a RDD with ('house_name', 'price') with both values as string. You would like to convert, price from string to float.
In PySpark, we can apply map and python float function to achieve this.

```
New_RDD = RawDataRDD.map(lambda (house_name, price): (house_name, float(x.price))    # this works
```

In PySpark 1.6 Dataframe, it does not work:

```
New_DF = rawdataDF.select('house name', float('price')) # did not work
```

Until a built in Pyspark function available, how to do achieve this conversion with a UDF?
I developed this conversion UDF as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def string_to_float(x):
    return float(x)

udfstring_to_float = udf(string_to_float, StringType())
rawdata.withColumn("house name", udfstring_to_float("price"))
```

Is there a better and much simpler way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html), you can use the `cast` function on a column like this:

```
rawdata.withColumn("house name", rawdata["price"].cast(DoubleType()).alias("price"))
```

Comment: This does not work for me @Jaco.  The OP says he is using pyspark 1.6 and the documentation *you* linked to is 1.3.  When i try this on 1.6 i get `AttributeError: 'DoubleType' object has no attribute 'alias'
`

Comment: Do you have the import `from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType` ? I am sure I tested this on PySpark 1.6 before posting.

Comment: FIX: Should be 
```rawdata.withColumn("house name",rawdata["price"].cast(DoubleType()).alias("price")```
instead

Answer (score 3):

The answer should be as follows:

```
>>> rawdata.printSchema()
root
 |-- house name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)

>>> rawdata=rawdata.withColumn('price',rawdata['price'].cast("float").alias('price'))

>>> rawdata.printSchema()
root
 |-- house name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: float (nullable = true)
```

As it is the shortest one-line code without using any user-defined function. You can see whether it worked correctly by using `printSchema()` function.