# SQL Split by delimiter to float elements

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am trying to split a string in to a list of float elements, but I am only able to get it as String elements.

Is it possible to convert each element to a float?

**Value in stringCol before:**

```
"1.123,-1.123"
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT *, SPLIT(stringCol,',') as arrayCol from df
```

**Value in arrayCol after:**

```
["1.123","-1.123"]
```

**Desired value in arrayCol after:**

```
[1.123,-1.123]
```

Comment: BTW: are you using mssql?  If not, please add the correct tag to your question.

Comment: I am using Pyspark (it is tagged).
The one you linked doesn't anwser how to convert elements in an array column for pyspark.

Comment: [How to convert DataFrame columns from string to float/double in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684018/how-to-convert-dataframe-columns-from-string-to-float-double-in-pyspark-1-6)

Comment: I am not trying to convert a column, I am trying to convert elements in each array inside the value of the column.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform  It 'transforms' a column to `int`, with a small change it should be possible to convert the columns to `float`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use libraries in Python:

```
import ast
List1 = ["1.123","-1.123"]
noquotes = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in List1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).